# Close the current page on click and open a new page?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, apex, buttonclick

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search Again" onclick="return window.open('/apex/customreport');" />
```

I am using currently this function on `onclick`. When I click on button, it is opening a new window. I want it in such a way that it has to close the current page and open the new page.

Comment: apex is a visualforce markup which used in salesofrce

Answer (score 1):

try

```
window.location.href='/apex/customreport';
```

Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

you can close the opener in the new opened window.... try this

```
<body onload="window.opener.close();">
```

if you dont have a body (for whatever reason?) you can put your javascript directly into your html file like this:

```
<script>window.opener.close();</script>
```

Comment: i dont have body on my program

Comment: where i can write the url can you elabrate this one